# Elasticsearch - Calculate Delay between Timestamps

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

How can I calculate the delay between timestamps without logstash, but with script_fields?

e.g. for this documents:

```
{
 "_source": {
  "name": "test1",
  "timestamp": "2021-12-30 12:30:00"
 }
}
{
 "_source": {
  "name": "test1",
  "timestamp": "2021-12-30 12:30:01"
 }
}
{
 "_source": {
  "name": "test1",
  "timestamp": "2021-12-30 12:30:03"
 }
}
```

I want to have a new field called "time_taken", so the expected documents should look like this:

```
{
 "_source": {
  "name": "test1",
  "timestamp": "2021-12-30 12:30:00"
 }
}
{
 "_source": {
  "name": "test1",
  "timestamp": "2021-12-30 12:30:01",
  "time_taken": "1"
 }
}
{
 "_source": {
  "name": "test1",
  "timestamp": "2021-12-30 12:30:03",
  "time_taken": "2"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided answer was inspired from [Painless example in Transforms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/transform-painless-examples.html#painless-bucket-script).

**The solution uses [Transforms API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-apis.html) and it has some limitations I recommend you to check them and see if it's fine for your use-case [Transform limitation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/transform-limitations.html)**.

First thing I created a mapping for the provided example:

```
PUT myindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keywords": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and insert some documents:

```
POST myindex/_doc
{
  "name": "test1",
  "timestamp":"2022-01-27T19:48:11Z"
}
POST myindex/_doc
{
  "name": "test1",
  "timestamp":"2022-01-27T19:50:11Z"
}
POST myindex/_doc
{
  "name": "test1",
  "timestamp":"2022-01-27T19:53:11Z"
}
POST myindex/_doc
{
  "name": "test2",
  "timestamp":"2022-01-27T19:35:11Z"
}
POST myindex/_doc
{
  "name": "test2",
  "timestamp":"2022-01-27T19:36:11Z"
}
```

Using the Transform API we can calculate for each aggregation the time length for each term:

```
POST _transform/_preview
{
  "source": {
    "index": "myindex"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "destindex"
  },
  "pivot": {
    "group_by": {
      "name": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "name.keywords"
        }
      }
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "latest_value": {
        "scripted_metric": {
          "init_script": "state.timestamp_latest = 0L;",
          "map_script": """
          def current_date = doc['timestamp'].getValue().toInstant().toEpochMilli();
          if (current_date > state.timestamp_latest)
          {state.timestamp_latest = current_date;}
        """,
          "combine_script": "return state",
          "reduce_script": """
          def last_doc = '';
          def timestamp_latest = 0L;
          for (s in states) {if (s.timestamp_latest > (timestamp_latest))
          {timestamp_latest = s.timestamp_latest;}}
          return timestamp_latest
        """
        }
      },
      "first_value": {
         "scripted_metric": {
          "init_script": "state.timestamp_first = 999999999999999L;",
          "map_script": """
          def current_date = doc['timestamp'].getValue().toInstant().toEpochMilli();
          if (current_date < state.timestamp_first)
          {state.timestamp_first = current_date;}
        """,
          "combine_script": "return state",
          "reduce_script": """
          def last_doc = '';
          def timestamp_first = 999999999999999L;
          for (s in states) {if (s.timestamp_first < (timestamp_first))
          {timestamp_first = s.timestamp_first;}}
          return timestamp_first
        """
        }
      },
      "time_length": {
        "bucket_script": {
          "buckets_path": {
            "min": "first_value.value",
            "max": "latest_value.value"
          },
          "script": "(params.max - params.min)/1000"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The output is as follow:

```
{
  "preview" : [
    {
      "time_length" : 300.0,
      "name" : "test1",
      "first_value" : 1643312891000,
      "latest_value" : 1643313191000
    },
    {
      "time_length" : 60.0,
      "name" : "test2",
      "first_value" : 1643312111000,
      "latest_value" : 1643312171000
    }
  ],
  "generated_dest_index" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "_meta" : {
        "_transform" : {
          "transform" : "transform-preview",
          "version" : {
            "created" : "7.15.1"
          },
          "creation_date_in_millis" : 1643400080594
        },
        "created_by" : "transform"
      },
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "number_of_shards" : "1",
        "auto_expand_replicas" : "0-1"
      }
    },
    "aliases" : { }
  }
}
```

## What's the script doing?

As you can see we are creating a term aggregation on the field `name.keywords`.  We used a scripted metric aggregation that has 4 steps:

- **init_script:** initiate a state, it's a space where you initialize your variables and their scope are global for all shards
- **map_script:** this step execute the code for each document, means you can iterate or do complex calculation on your documents like if you were coding in a high-level programming language like python or java (avoid doing heavy calculation or it will slower your aggregation)
- **combine_script:** here we tell elasticsearch to return the state from each shard
- **reduce_script:** it's the final step where we iterate over the result of each shard from the previous step (aka `combine script`) to calculate the first/latest timestamp for each aggregation.

Finally, in the `bucket script`, we calculate the difference given the `first_value` and `latest_value`, we divided by `1000` because the timestamp field is stored in epoch millis. `time_length` unit is in seconds.

More information about scripted metric aggregation: [Scripted metrics](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-scripted-metric-aggregation.html).

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your very detailed help, the whole thing works great on the "seconds" level, but not on the "millisecond" level, do you have any idea? I also have no unique id or something (not even the field 'name'), only the single timestamp.

https://imgur.com/a/Rsp0MFo

should i maybe add something like a custom unique id per runtime field?

btw, if i do "terms": { "field": "@timestamp.keywords" }, the "preview" array does not work then

Comment: this is what it looks like when i take a date without milliseconds:
https://imgur.com/a/qj3SPgJ

Comment: Happy to hear that it worked! For your first problem conerning "seconds" I think your data are stored in unix format, meaning in seconds (I don't see 3 zeros at teh end of your timestamp). To be sure check https://www.epochconverter.com/ and try to convert the preview result of fields `first_value` and `last_value` in human readable format.

Comment: For your second problem, you can't do an aggregation in @timestamp.keywords, because keyword field doesn't exist, instead you can do a `date_histogram` like: ` "group_by": {
     "hist": {
       "date_histogram": {
         "field": "timestamp",
         "fixed_interval": "1h"
       }
     }
    }`

Comment: But sure if you can add a keyword field in your document it will be fine too.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer, i tried this with group_by and it seems to work, however the calculation does not work on millisecond level, although milliseconds are also specified: https://imgur.com/a/Gk4gtB3 the calculation also does not work if i do e.g. max/1000 - min/1000

Comment: if i do group_by with the index example from you i get a "time_length" of 0 everywhere too

Comment: now i have changed my second timestamp field to the same format as in your example with keywords, but the calculation is always 0 there too: https://imgur.com/a/zb4In5c

Comment: From your screenshot just realized that `first_value` and `last_value` are equal, could be a data quality problem. You can filter your output by adding an aggregation after `"time_length"`, like this: `// .... "time_length": { // rest of code } , "aggs": { "bucket_selector": { "buckets_path": {"timeLength":"time_length"},"script": "params.timeLength > 0}}`.

One more thing, it's only a `preview` result and is limited up to 100 results.

Comment: this is the error i have as soon as i work with milliseconds. I also have only about 80 docs and almost every one has a delay of at least 1 millisecond. As soon as I work with seconds it shows a delay, after that it just says time_length = 0, which you can see from the other screenshots.

Comment: this is what the expected result should look like: https://imgur.com/a/Ch8Mo5y

Comment: You will always get 0 because `first_value` and `last_value` are equal, even if you have milliseconds or not you will always have 0. In your last screenshot, you can't use a date value in `name` field because you'll have always have a bucket that contains one single document. Thus `first_value` and `last_value` are the same. You need to have a value in `name` as a term. Can you send an example of a source document you have?

Comment: today i also took a close look at the subject matter in the docs and realized that it doesn't work like that. Here is the document that I use: https://pastebin.com/jX72Z6g0

Comment: the log is generated by a third party software where i have no influence, maybe the use of logstash is necessary after all? If so do you have an idea?

Comment: Thank you for providing an example of log, but I am wondering what's your use case, in other words, what's the question you are trying to answer based on the sample?

Comment: this is my expected result: https://imgur.com/a/VJufcjP A new field "time_taken" which in best case calculates in "ms" the used time between the timestamp in the documents. I would like to sort them later in a table so that I can analyze which step took the longest in the log.

Comment: I see, if you want to calculate the time taken for each process, you can group by the field `ProcessId` or `threadId` depending on your use-case, this way I think you'll have correct results.

Comment: I then get only one result https://imgur.com/a/AKT1cPk

Comment: I don't know how many `processId` you have but before that do a bucket aggregation on `processId`, like this: `GET yourindex/_search {"size":0,   "aggs": {
    "processId": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "ProcessId.keyword",
        "size": 65000
      }
    }
  }` if you get only one bucket returned that means your transform's working correctly, if not try another field maybe `threadId`.